# ReactJs if else in render

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

Having some weird situation at least weird for me. I'm building timeline component so far so good. In case user timeline is empty i want to render different react class
Here a portion of the code i did

```
var Timeline = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        data: [],
        page: 0,
        loadingFlag: false
    }
},
loadTimelineFromServer: function() {
    var nextPage = this.state.page + 1;
    var url = this.props.url + '?page=' + nextPage;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: true,
        success: function(response) {
            if (this.isMounted()) {
                this.setState({
                    data: this.state.data.concat(response.data),
                    loadingFlag: false,
                    page: nextPage
                });
            }
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
    });
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadTimelineFromServer();
},
render: function() {
    var items = this.state.data;
    var renderer;
    if (items.length) {
        renderer = <TimelineList data=items />
    } else {
        renderer = <EmptyTimeline />
    }

    return (
        <div>
        {renderer}
        </div>
    );
} 
});
```

**EDIT** : the error fired from firebug
Error: Parse Error: Line 71: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text
    at http://qfriends.dev/js/components/socialnetwork/user_timeline.js:71:20 ...pointing to this `<TimelineList data=items />`

Comment: worth mentioning i followed steps from reactjs docs page http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html

Comment: What's not working? Do you see anything at all? Do you get any errors? A bit more information would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<TimelineList data=items />` is not valid JSX.  You should use curly braces to pass a javascript expression as a prop: `<TimelineList data={items} />`.

Comment: Thanks i almost forgot about this rule! U saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add either a semicolon to the end:

```
if (items.length) {
    renderer = <TimelineList data=items />;
} else {
    renderer = <EmptyTimeline />;
}
```

or do it like this:

```
if (items.length) {
    renderer = (
        <TimelineList data=items />
    );
} else {
    renderer = (
        <EmptyTimeline />
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time sir! Really appreciate the efforts